# Flex / Javascript: overlay components

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

I would like to have **one image** in the background and above it have **another image** (transparent) and some **text description**.

I have tried the following code but it does not work as it allocates three equals spaces to the three components.

Is there a way to overlay components on top of each other?

**Image code**:

```
export default ({segments, value, onPress}: Props) => {
  return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Image
          style={styles.backdrop}
          source={{uri: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg'}}
        />
        <Image
          style={styles.backdrop}
          source={{uri: 'https://i1.wp.com/sharmajitech.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/4-stars.jpg'}}
        />
        <Text style={styles.headline}>
            <Text>
              {"Some text"} 
              </Text>
              <Text>
              {"Other text"} 
              </Text>
          </Text>
      </View>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
<View
  style={{
    flex: 0.4,
    backgroundColor: 'silver',
  }}
>
 {
    <HeroImageTwo
    segments={[
      {label: "This is much longer", value: "a"},
      {label: "b", value: "b"},
    ]}
    value="a"
    onPress={action("press")}
  /> }
 </View>
```

Actual result:

- the 3 components occupy the same width height and there is no overlay

Desired result:

- Have the first image as background and the text and other image overplayed

Comment: give position absolute to the other two components to position them above the 3rd component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`position`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) property from CSS to achieve desired behavior.

> The position property specifies the type of positioning method used
>   for an element (static, relative, fixed, absolute or sticky).

**Example** ([*Working Snack*](https://snack.expo.io/ryHviVU9M))

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('./assets/overlay1.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.image} />
        <Image source={require('./assets/overlay2.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.image} />
        <Image source={require('./assets/overlay3.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.image} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 250
  }
});
```